# Easiest way to unstuck transaction because of EIP-2929 with accesslist

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm new to low level of sending tx. I have a problem that contract uses .send() for sending funds to my Gnosis address. Because of [EIP-2929](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2929) & [EIP-2930](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2930).

I have read few articles about it (e.g. [this](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5249851-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe),[this](https://hackmd.io/@fvictorio/gas-costs-after-berlin),[this](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2930), and few questions here on SE...).
I don't want to use some "random" code from web that wants me to use mnenonic e.g. [folia-app github repo](https://github.com/folia-app/eip-2929)

Is there a way in Gnosis wallet to include accesslist via UI under some "advanced parameters"?
Or is there another easier way to do it for someone with limited knowledge of lowlever ETH interaction?

Comment: anyone? how to run folia-app, is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is not possible because not every wallet accepts access lists. For example, Metamask ignores them.

Comment: Sure, but my question is about Gnome wallet. If there is already possibility to "prepay" for gas via accesslist from UI, but i don't find it. Or is there just the script way to do it.